# UIView is not resizing width when device has changed

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, constraints

I have an UIView in my Storyboard. Leading and Trailing is 16, width of the element is not fixed.

[image]

I am appending UILabels to this UIView (-container), which will move to the next "row", when the new and existing UILabel exceeds the width of the container. The "containerWidth" (UIView.frame.size.width) is 382.

```
**// If current X + label width will be greater than container view width
// .. move to next row**
if (currentOriginX + labelHashtag.frame.width > containerWidth) {
      currentOriginX = 0
      currentOriginY += tagHeight + tagSpacingY
      }
```

It works fine for iPhone XSM:

[image]

But when I run my code on an iPhone 8, the container width is still 382 and the UILabels appearing out of my screen:

[image]

**Why is the size of my UIView always the same? Why is there no automatically resizing when I use constraints, depending on the device?**

Comment: basically this kind of designs should be handle with UICollectionView. What is your originX? try like GetMaxWidth(labelHashtag) instead of `labelHashtag.frame.width`

Comment: It could be because the label gets a larger size than expected, as the size is not jet determined before adding to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you add the labels from? If you add them from `viewDidLoad()` method, then this is the expected outcome, because your container view will have the exact same width as in the storyboard at that point, then it will be resized with respect to the device screen size. You can use `viewDidAppear(_:)` method to layout the labels, but you'll have to take care as there could be a small delay from the point of screen appearance and the labels being rendered on the screen.

Do not use `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` to create and add the labels, because that method will be called multiple times. However, you can use `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` to recompute the position of the labels (it would be, in fact, the approach I would recommend).

So my recommendation is:

1. Create the labels in `viewDidLoad()` method
2. Take care to have a reference to your labels (an array most probably)
3. In `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` compute the positions of the labels.

Comment: Vlad, this makes totally sense to me. Thank you. I had a wrong concept in my head about the automatic resizing. One problem I have in your approach: I am using a „Page“ View. And when a user tries to make the Page „larger“ by a swipe gesture to the top, viewDidLayoutSubies() will be called again. I am sure there is a method to prevent this, right now I solved this problem by getting the width value of the device minus constraints. But I am sure your approach is correct. Thank you